# remove rows from the dataframe that don't exist in the list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
29                             tech is a fucking bloodbath.
219       only 3 things guaranteed in life ATH taxes a...
255       market is at ath in zombie economy\n\nmarket c...
276       my aapl watch reminding me to breathe while i...
```

I have a list

```
names = 
['ATH', 'CRSR', 'GME', 'AMC', 'TSLA', 'MVIS', 'SPCE', 'CLNE', 'AAPL', 'WKHS']
```

My code looks like this

```
for ticker in top_tickers:
    df_ticker_lower = item[item.text.str.contains(ticker.lower())]
    df_ticker_upper = item[item.text.str.contains(ticker.upper())]
    df_ticker = pd.concat([df_ticker_lower, df_ticker_upper], axis=0)
    df_ticker['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df_ticker.dt)


def dedup(sentence, to_dedup):
    for word in to_dedup:
        while sentence.split().count(word) > 3:
            sentence = ''.join(sentence.rsplit(word, 1)).replace('  ', ' ')
    return sentence

def foo(row):
    global names
    sentence = row['text']
    return dedup(sentence, names)
df_ticker['text'] = df_ticker.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

What I want to do is to keep rows that that have any words from the list. The important part is that if anything surrounds any word from the list the row should be removed.
In this case row 29 needs to be removed since bloodbath is a word that contains ath. If it would be separated I would keep this row but in this case I want this row to be removed
Appreciate your help

Comment: How about `df[df_ticker['text'].str.contains('|'.join(names))]` ?

Comment: gives an error pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries `\b\b` for omit like `bloodbath` words in [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in names)
df = df[df['text'].str.contains(pat,case=False,na=True)]
print (df)
                                                text
1         only 3 things guaranteed in life ATH taxes
2                 market is at ath in zombie economy
4   my aapl watch reminding me to breathe while i...
```

If need extract first matched value:

```
import re

names = ['ATH', 'CRSR', 'GME', 'AMC', 'TSLA', 'MVIS', 'SPCE', 'CLNE', 'AAPL', 'WKHS']

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in names)
df['new'] = df['text'].str.extract(f'({pat})', flags=re.I)
print (df)
                                                text   new
0                       tech is a fucking bloodbath.   NaN
1         only 3 things guaranteed in life ATH taxes   ATH
2                 market is at ath in zombie economy   ath
3                                          market c.   NaN
4   my aapl watch reminding me to breathe while i...  aapl
```

Or all matched values to lists:

```
import re

names = ['ATH', 'CRSR', 'GME', 'AMC', 'TSLA', 'MVIS', 'SPCE', 'CLNE', 'AAPL', 'WKHS']

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in names)
df['new'] = df['text'].str.findall(pat, flags=re.I)
print (df)
                                                text     new
0                       tech is a fucking bloodbath.      []
1         only 3 things guaranteed in life ATH taxes   [ATH]
2                 market is at ath in zombie economy   [ath]
3                                          market c.      []
4   my aapl watch reminding me to breathe while i...  [aapl]
```

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation is that you only want to keep the rows that contains any of the words in the word list that **match as a whole word, instead of match as partial word**.  In this case, you can use:

```
names = ['ATH', 'CRSR', 'GME', 'AMC', 'TSLA', 'MVIS', 'SPCE', 'CLNE', 'AAPL', 'WKHS']

pattern = r'\b' + '|'.join(names) + r'\b'

df_ticker.loc[df_ticker['text'].str.contains(pattern, case=False)]
```

Here, we used a pair of regex meta-characters `\b` to enclose the word list to ensure only whole word match.

**Result:**

**Only the last 3 rows are returned, as required:**

```
                                                  text
219    only 3 things guaranteed in life ATH taxes a...
255  market is at ath in zombie economy\n\nmarket c...
276   my aapl watch reminding me to breathe while i...
```

Comment: 40seconds difference ;)

Comment: @SeaBean,  he means 40sec difference in posting the answer :-) , because logic is same.

Comment: here is what I tried df['text'] = df['text'].str.upper()
df = df[df['text'].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: any([n in x for n in names]))].

Comment: @KarnKumar   I see.  Thanks!  Such small time difference :-D

Comment: for both the solution +1  with word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the list values while using `str.contains`.

### DataFrame:

```
>>> df
                                                text
0                       tech is a fucking bloodbath.
1    only 3 things guaranteed in life ATH taxes a...
2  market is at ath in zombie economy\n\nmarket c...
3   my aapl watch reminding me to breathe while i...
```

### List Values to be matched:

```
>>> names
['ATH', 'CRSR', 'GME', 'AMC', 'TSLA', 'MVIS', 'SPCE', 'CLNE', 'AAPL', 'WKHS']
```

### Result:

```
>>> df[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(names))]
                                              text
1  only 3 things guaranteed in life ATH taxes a...
```

If you are looking for an explicit word to be matched with case sensitiveness, then i will do construct my list obj as follows and it will work.

```
>>> names = [' ATH ', ' CRSR ', ' GME ', ' AMC ', ' TSLA ', ' MVIS ', ' SPCE ', ' CLNE ', ' AAPL ', ' WKHS ']

>>> df[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(names))]
                                              text
1  only 3 things guaranteed in life ATH taxes a...
>>> df[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(names),case=False)]
                                                text
1    only 3 things guaranteed in life ATH taxes a...
2  market is at ath in zombie economy\n\nmarket c...
3   my aapl watch reminding me to breathe while i...
```

### To be idiomatic :-)

as we know, we are looking for exact word match, hence we can use space padding with formatter itself to achieve the same.

```
>>> patt = '|'.join(' {} '.format(x) for x in names)
>>> df[df['text'].str.contains(patt,case=False)]
                                                text
1    only 3 things guaranteed in life ATH taxes a...
2  market is at ath in zombie economy\n\nmarket c...
3   my aapl watch reminding me to breathe while i...
```

Try to make the data simpler at its outset itself, rather of wrangling it later  :-)

Comment: I want to keep lower case as well, so rows 1,2,3 would be kept